# How do I add a listener to JavaScript Object variable?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have an object generated by [this code](http://pastebin.com/ns9Znt5y), but I can only use it when its obj.**ready** property is == true.
I can use only pure JavaScript or Prototypejs.
It script is inserted as source (< script src=...).

Is there a way to detect when the object is ready to use?
I tried to put observer on dom:loaded, but it didn't work.

I use

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('someTextHere');
PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash();
```

The second line doesnt work because the object is not ready yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code here. Reduce it to the most relevant part only.

Comment: Hi Felix. The code in the library is not relevant, but I'll add other parts here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no infrastructure of events there then the only option is to do polling:

```
function whenReady(obj, callback) {
  var iid = setInterval(function() {
    if(obj.ready) {
      callback();
      clearInterval(iid);
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

And to use it as:

```
PagSeguroDirectPayment.setSessionId('someTextHere');
whenReady(PagSeguroDirectPayment, function() {
  PagSeguroDirectPayment.getSenderHash(); 
});
```

Comment: I thought about interval, but I'm afraid that there's a less agressive option. =)  But it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RicardoMartins Another approach would be to use `Object.observe(callback)` so without polling but it a) didn't land into browsers widely and b) not too much less "aggressive" than polling. But I suspect that code you citing has mechanism of events allowing you to subscribe on "ready" event.